# Silverstripe 4 bulk image upload and create Dataobject from each image

Tags: image, file-upload, silverstripe, data-objects

This is a question about creating DataObjects from bulk-Uploaded images.

Normally i use Colymba\BulkUpload\BulkUploader in this way:

(all pseudo code)

e.g.:

And a normal setup with

(Modeladmin)

ProductCategorie has_many Products

One Product has_many Images.

But in my actual scenario i like to bulk-Upload many Images and create a Product from each Uploaded Image. How can this be made? Best result would be a Product-Category to choose from before uploading images (Dropdown).
Is there a hook like 'afterUpload'  to create the Dataobjects ?

Could you please guide me to a workable solution with pseudo-code ?

Maybe a helper-class to upload and create the Products-DataObjects ?

Thanks. sepp.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial problem to solve.
Your best bet is probably looking at the code  from the bulk uploader and then using that as a reference to create your own custom bulk uploader that does what you need it to do.